# Group by name in MVC foreach loop to get a count

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

The below code is what I am currently running in a razor view.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.intbyAnalysts.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct())
{
    <li>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => item)
    </li>

}
```

This brings me back the names that I need. I was wondering is there any way of doing a count on this as well so it could bring me back the list of name plus count the number of record to so like the below:

```
    John 5 
    Sam  6 
    Mary 8 
    etc
```

It does not work but I was thinking something like the below:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.intbyAnalysts.GroupBy(x => x.Name)) {
    <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.item))
    </td>    
    <td>
     @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.item.Count())
    </td>      
}
```

Again this doesn't work but I was also thinking something like the below:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.intbyAnalysts.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                                          .Select(n => new {n.Name, n.Count }))
```

Any help work by greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not about MVC nor Razor. You just need to create a model IEnumerable<(string name, int count)> and pass it to a view. Why do you use "DisplayFor" and when you said "its not working" - what is not working?

Comment: I was wondering if I could do it in a linq query with out making another model. With regard to the DisplayFor I am new to using razor pages so unsure what the best way to display the results would be.

Comment: Just use @ symbol then specify data source, like @Model.Items[0] etc. It is always good to create separate model...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move Linq logic to model class instead of putting it inside view...

This works for me, no need to explain this simple code i think:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var model = new Model();
            model.Items.Add( new Item { Name = "item1" } );
            model.Items.Add( new Item { Name = "item1" } );
            model.Items.Add( new Item { Name = "item1" } );
            model.Items.Add( new Item { Name = "item2" } );
            model.Items.Add( new Item { Name = "item2" } );
            model.Items.Add( new Item { Name = "item3" } );

            foreach (var entry in model.ItemNameAndCount)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( entry.name + ": " + entry.count );
            }
        }

        public class Model
        {
            public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Item>();

            public IEnumerable<(string name, int count)> ItemNameAndCount
               => Items.GroupBy( x => x.Name )
                       .Select( group =>
                            (
                              name: group.Key,
                              count: group.Count()
                            )
                        );
        }

        public class Item
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need item.Name == group.Key predicate inside Count? This count will return number of items in current group only anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine, except it should be `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.item.Key))` in first `td` (not just `x.item`).

Does this fix the issue for you? If not, could you please update the question with some error details.